# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"r_version"' - While converting temperature to Fahrenheit

Tags: pyspark, rdd

Looking out for any help with the error that I am getting as stated in the title. I have followed similar questions and tried what is mentioned here but still doesn't help.

I have below data in a file that i am trying to run my pyspark code on.

[image]

below is the code which seems to be giving this error

```
def parseLine(line):
    fields = line.split(',')
    stationID = fields[0]
    entryType = fields[2]
    temperature = float(fields[3]) * 0.1 * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0
    return (stationID, entryType, temperature)

lines = sc.textFile("<file>")
parsedLines = lines.map(parseLine)
```

Column 4th which will be read as 3rd field in pyspark is a numerical field. So I am wondering why the error of converting string to float? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. I realised after going through my code again that I was reading a wrong file which was STRING in 4th column. I corrected the file name and it worked.